# mozrepl on opensuse-linux 12.1 brings troubles during the installation

Tags: perl, parsing, mechanize, mozilla, opensuse

I want to install mozrepl on OpenSUSE version 12.1. It gets pretty tricky - note Mozrepl is a additional part that is needed by the WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::

I had a bunch of troubles with mozRepl - and I tried to follow the first 3-4 steps from  CPAN. I tried to install it with `zypper` in or with the repo: https://github.com/bard/mozrepl.github

See many good links and ressources regarding Mechanize - Firefox - Troubleshooting
https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=mozrepl
https://github.com/bard/mozrepl.github

Comment: Please post the exact commands that you ran and the exact error messages you got.

Comment: A concrete question along with some error messages and information would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MozRepl is a plugin in firefox. You need to install it from Mozilla AppStore.

Do you tried to install from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/?